# integrating GWT and angular2

Tags: javascript, java, angular, gwt

I have a big project in GWT and i'm trying to integrate Angular2 with it. ([angular2-gwt](https://github.com/ltearno/angular2-gwt) is not an option as i'm running on version 2.7 and can't migrate to 2.8 at the time)

I'm facing a couple of problems i don't seem to know how to face:

1) I heard that you can use JSNI to use the angular app but i didn't seem to be able to do that or to find any information about it. how does it work and what can i do with it? (invoke a function is an option?)

2) I tried to add the selector tag of the angular app to the GWT entry point html and that works well but when i'm trying to add the selector to a .ui.xml file (UI Binding) it doesn't work, why?

3) Is there an option to invoke the GWT client side from a servlet? What i mean is i'm at the angular2 app and use a rest call, can this rest call invoke something on the GWT Client side?

Thanks!

Comment: About 1): we have an AngularJS app which has to work with an internal `iframe`. Inside the `iframe` we get access to the parent Angular app `$scope` like this: `window.parent.angular.element(window.frameElement).scope();`. Since GWT also runs inside an `iframe`, you can probably translate that to JSNI code to use the Angular app from GWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I should note that migration from GWT 2.7 to GWT 2.8 was pretty painless for me. I updated my apps and didn't had any major issue (some Maven dependencies that changed, some flag here and there, etc). 
I'm mentioning this because native JS support is vastly improved in GWT 2.8 vs GWT 2.7, so if at all possible you really should do the switch.

Regardless, in GWT 2.7:

1. You can call any kind of JS from GWT like this:

`public static native void sayHello() /*-{
    $wnd.alert("Hello world!");
}-*/;`

Note the `$wnd` construction which is placeholder for the "global" namespace in JS (i.e. in JS you'd simply call `alert()`  without using a specific namespace).

Please be aware however, that if you're interfacing with *a lot* of JS native code (such as using complex objects from angular), you will pay a hefty price for going this route. This route is good for when you want to invoke a function or two from JS, but other than this I don't recommend it.
You could have a look for example at the source code of `gwt-openlayers` at http://www.gwtopenlayers.org/ and see how it looks like for a more complex example (this library wraps a lot of native JS)

2. I don't really know any angular, but the `.ui.xml` is a special beast. Some obfuscation takes place in the background / some other stuff happens. The closest you will get to HTML, is to put some stuff inside a `g:HTMLPanel` widget, but to my knowledge, you can't really have JS in there.
3. A bit confusing what you're asking here. You can't easily invoke any client-side code from a server-side servlet, unless you insist; then, you could do workarounds and use techniques such as long polls, etc, but I'm not a big fan of those. I can expand more on the subject, but it appears that my understanding of your point might be lacking.

Comment: First, thanks for your comment. second, i'm familiar with the native JS but my question is how i can invoke angular functions/members from the JSNI. Also, i guess your right about the javascript in the HTMLPanel because it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, in this case perhaps I misunderstand things. Isn't it already possible to invoke angular functions/members from the JSNI just like you do with any other native JS? What is stopping you from doing this, what is the error?
All I can think of is that perhaps you're not using the `$wnd/$doc` namespaces and trying to access stuff directly (i.e. you invoke `alert()` instead of `$wnd.alert()`)
The simplest way to solve this, is to show one angular code invocation in native JS, and how you're trying to accomplish the same thing via GWT, and what is the error you're getting.